# What is the established algebraic form for interleaving or zipping a pair of equal length sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am interleaving elements from two sets, A and B, of equal length.

What is the most well established way of presenting this, algebraically?

This is what I have:

$$ (x,y) \forall x,y \in A,B $$

I have not found a reference example yet.

Comment: There is the (Cartesian product) set $A\times B=\{(a,b)|a\in A,\, b\in B\}$ But I don't think that is what you want. I think what you are looking for may be a bijection (or equivalent to one) but there is no canonical choice, especially for sets that aren't finite.

Comment: Sets are _unordered_ collections of elements, so it doesn't really make sense to specify "interleaving" them. You should be speaking about "lists" or "sequences" instead, but then you can't rely on the $\in$ relation telling you everything about them.

Comment: By interleaving, do you mean taking ordered sets $[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$, $[b_1, \ldots, b_n]$, and forming the ordered set $[a_1, b_1, \ldots, a_n, b_n]$?

Comment: @Travis, Henning, thanks - I do mean ordered sets, as per Travis' comment

Comment: I don't think there's an established notation for this, but one can write the interwoven ordered set/finite sequence efficiently using piecewise notation. This is the sort of notion for which is worth choosing or even inventing a new notation for (in both cases with explanation of course) if you're going to use it often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is fine. You could also write $ A × B $.